# jQuery fade in/out div to a different div?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have a div fade out, then fade in at the same place with a different div with different content when you click a link or button?

It'd obviously use the `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` functions but I'm not sure what all the code would look like, especially with positioning, and the ability to do it twice on the same page.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ and http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Can you post any related code?

Comment: Of the same time ?? You mean of the same type ?? I would reword what you're asking for, it's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant at the same place. So you click a button, the current div fades out, then another div fades in where the previous div faded out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're looking to fade out one `</div>` then fade in a different one:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none"></div>
<div><a href="#" id="triggerButton">Swap Divs</a></div>

$('#triggerButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div1').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#div2').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

If you're looking to replace the `</div>` that is faded out in the same place with a different one:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div><a href="#" id="triggerButton">Swap Divs</a></div>

$('#triggerButton').click(function(e){    
    $('#div1').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#div1').replace('<div id="div2"></div>').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this triggered? And I'm guessing that in the first example (which is what I want to happen, having a div fade out then a new one fade in) would require some css too, to hide `div2` before it is shown?

Comment: @Charlie It can be triggered by pretty much any event in jQuery; I've edited the answer to display it being changed by a click event on an anchor tag. Also added display: none to hide the second div.

Answer (score 10):

Here are two boxes that alternate fading in and out on top of one another: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3XwZv/.

The two boxes are positioned on top of one another using `position: absolute` in a `position: relative` container.

One fades out, the other fades in and when one completes, they reverse the process.  The jQuery code looks like this:

```
var fadeinBox = $("#box2");
var fadeoutBox = $("#box1");

function fade() {
    fadeinBox.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    fadeoutBox.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        // swap in/out
        var temp = fadeinBox;
        fadeinBox = fadeoutBox;
        fadeoutBox = temp;
        // start over again
        setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    });
}

// start the process
fade();
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#wrapper {position: relative;}

#box1 {background-color: #F00;}
#box2 {background-color: #00F;  display: none;}
```

Comment: If you have links in each of the boxes that are fading in and out, will the links still work?

Comment: @nicholaschris - only the top-most link will work since the objects are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```
$("#element1").fadeOut();
$("#element2").fadeIn();
```