# Replace a empty space with new content after CSS transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here's the situation:

- Got 3 different pages with different content.
- All those pages have a link to the rest of the pages.
- When you click one of them, the actual page fades out and the desired one fades into the viewport via CSS transitions triggered by JavaScript.

So far, so good, so what's the problem?

- The new page does not replace the old page space and position, it stays below the old one.

The desired efect I want to achieve is when you click a new page, it fades in into the exactly same position the old page was, intead of just appearing below and leaving an empty espace above.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(this);
  var $next = $('#' + $(this).attr('href'));
  $target.parent().removeClass('show');
  $target.parent().addClass('hide');
  $next.removeClass('hide');
  $next.addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page1" class="show">
  Page 1 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page2" class="btn">Show Page 2 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page3" class="btn">Show Page 3 and hide this page</a>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="hide">
  Page 2 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page1" class="btn">Show Page 1 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page3" class="btn">Show Page 3 and hide this page</a>
</div>

<div id="page3" class="hide">
  Page 3 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page1" class="btn">Show Page 1 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page2" class="btn">Show Page 2 and hide this page</a>
</div>
```

- Note: I've already tryed with `position: absolute` but someway it has a bug. Also with `display: none` but this can't allow transitions/animations and the fade out/in is a must.

I really appreciate your time and efforts! Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with slight changes

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(this);
  var $next = $('#' + $(this).attr('href'));
  $('.page').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  $next.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.page.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
.page.show {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page1" class="show page">
  Page 1 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page2" class="btn">Show Page 2 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page3" class="btn">Show Page 3 and hide this page</a>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="hide page">
  Page 2 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page1" class="btn">Show Page 1 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page3" class="btn">Show Page 3 and hide this page</a>
</div>

<div id="page3" class="hide page">
  Page 3 Content
  <br>
  <a href="page1" class="btn">Show Page 1 and hide this page</a>
  <br>
  <a href="page2" class="btn">Show Page 2 and hide this page</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL04kvb5/) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773843/3591300).
it doesn't need css either but you need inline style. you can replace the inline style as well if you want.

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(this);
  var $next = $('#' + $(this).attr('href'));

  $target.parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
       $next.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this functional alternative to my problem! ;)